# Visual Studio Extensibility: Get encoding of ProjectItem/TextDocument

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

If I have a `ProjectItem` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)), how do I get its its encoding as detected by Visual Studio?

I want to get the same result as shown in this dialog:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you can get it directly from the `ProjectItem`.  I believe you need to wait for the actual document to be open as the encoding is detected at that time.  At that time you should have an `ITextBuffer` and can get the `Encoding` this way

```
ITextDocumentFactoryService factoryService = ...;
ITextBuffer textBuffer = ...;
ITextDocument textDocument;
if (factoryService.TryGetTextDocument(textBuffer, out textDocument)) { 
  Encoding encoding = textDocument.Encoding;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that should do it.